# Is it possible to add multiple images in a single uiimageview?

Tags: ipad, uiimageview, uiimage

I have an imageview in which I want an image to be set. My designer have given me an image which is of the same height of imageview but the width is 1/10th of the imageview. He asked me to repeat it inside the imageview like a texture.

Is it possible to add multiple images to an imageview?  I know I can do it by using 10 imageviews for each reptition.  Is there anyother way like the texture thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Important Edit***:

*While the answer below is correct, I answered this too literally and didn't suggest the appropriate alternative.*

A `UIImageView` can only have one image, but you can fill a `UIView` with a repeating pattern by using `UIColor`'s `colorWithPatternImage` method:

```
// myView is the UIView to fill
// myImage is the UIImage to use as a fill pattern

myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:myImage];
```

---

*Old Answer*

No, only one UIImage per UIImageView. Your designer should repeat it himself and give you an image of the appropriate size. The iPhone is not the web, requirements are different.